# How to debug the Enqueue Call function in Retrofit when the request is not completing successfully

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, retrofit2, okhttp

within my code I am making a call to an API using retrofit . I have put breakpoints on the line 
if `(response.isSuccessful())`  but that break point is never hit . I would like to know why this happens 
because when I placed this exact same code in another fragment and it worked just fine I was able to retrieve the 
results from API but in this fragment the call does not work . I also put a break point on on failure `public void onFailure` to check if 
maybe the call is failing but that break point is also never hit which means that the call to server is not failing but for some reason 
the entire block of code in the `public void OnResponse` is being skipped. 
I am now suspecting that there is code within my fragment which is intereferring with the retrofit call .
 I have placed the code for my fragment below

```
package com.xera.deviceinsight.home;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.Errors;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.Globals;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.R;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.api.OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.api.Results;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.net.Claritech;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.net.ClaritechClient;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.receivers.IEvent;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.sensors.IotTabFragment;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.sensors.ItemClickedEvent;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.structs.DistanceUpdatedEvent;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.structs.HelloWorldEvent;
import com.xera.deviceinsight.structs.OrganisationDeviceSensorsEvent;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class CostCentreListFragment  extends Fragment {

   public static final String TAG = Globals.TAG + ".ALF";
   ViewPager mViewPager;
   ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
   ExpandableListView expListView;
   List<String> listDataHeader;
   HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
   public List<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult> Items;
   public String currentReportingGroup;
   private ViewPager viewPager;
   private IEvent onDeviceSensorsObtained;
   private IEvent event;
   public List sensorList;


   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
     // if (!eventBus.isRegistered(this)) eventBus.register(this);
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_expandable, container, false);
      AQuery aq = new AQuery(view);
      getDeviceSensorCostCentres();
      load(view);
      return view;
   }

   private void load(View view)
   {
      expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
      //EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickedEvent(IotTabFragment.TAB_SENSOR));
      getDeviceSensorCostCentres();
      prepareListData();
      listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
      expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
      expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //Nothing here ever fires
            System.err.println("child clicked");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "child clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Navigate to second tab
           // EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickedEvent(IotTabFragment.TAB_SENSOR));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickedEvent(IotTabFragment.TAB_USAGE));
            return true;
         }
      });
   }
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
      EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
      super.onPause();
   }
   private void getDeviceSensorCostCentres() {
      //int costCentreID =0
      final Context context = this.getActivity();
      ClaritechClient client = new ClaritechClient(context);

      Claritech.api(context).getDeviceSensorCostCentres(0).enqueue(new Callback<Results<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult>>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<Results<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult>> call, Response<Results<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
               // Reload data source
               Items.clear();
               Items.addAll(response.body());
               //ItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: ");
            }
         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<Results<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult>> call, Throwable t) {
            Errors.handleException(t);


         }
     });
    }


  public void onEvent(OrganisationDeviceSensorsEvent event){
       String Tag  ="";
       sensorList = event.deviceSensors;
       Log.i("EventBus",Tag);
       //prepareSensorListData();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.deviceSensors, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     };

   private void prepareListData() {
      listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
      listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      // Adding child data
      listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
      listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
      listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");
      List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
      top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
      top250.add("The Godfather");
      top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
      top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
      top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
      top250.add("The Dark Knight");
      top250.add("12 Angry Men");

      List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
      nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
      nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
      nowShowing.add("Turbo");
      nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
      nowShowing.add("Red 2");
      nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

      List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
      comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
      comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
      comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
      comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
      comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

      listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
      listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
      listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
   }

      };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to call a method which makes an api call then immediately after that I wanted to call another method which conflicts with retrofit because it makes its calls asynchronously therefore before completing the request it would jump into the next method . I removed the second method load() and placed it within the onresponse